# Automator Help: copying and renamig files from one static folder to one created dynamically

Tags: finder, automator, folders

I am curious to see how can I achieve this action.

So far, I created an automator that asks 3 questions: a ticket number, the name of a project and the type of project.

That creates a series of folders with the name "ticket x - project a (project type) - assets", and a subsequent set of more folders that change the last bit to accommodate recordings, lists and so forth.

We are good there. But now, I have a separate folder that always lives in the same location, with some formats that I need to place inside those newly created folders, and hopefully rename them (later).

I can Get Specified Finder Items to locate the first format, but when I want to Copy that Finder Item to the folders, I encounter that all those paths to the folders I created dynamically cannot be accessed, because the Copy Finder Items TO: does not take existing variables, only new ones.

So, can I save those paths somehow and then pass them to the recipient folder? It's the same when renaming. I can only pass text to the dialog box, not a variable that I just created.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From the `Copy Finder Items` "To:" menu, select "New Variable" and give it an appropriate name. Then after that, you can use the `Set Value of Variable` to set the value of the newly created variable. Note that you must do this above your `Copy Finder Items` action so that the variable is set before the copy operation happens.

Example workflow:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was finally able to make the path I had just created into a variable, then find the item, copy to the new path and then rename it according to the structure I just created. My life is much easier right now.